# Dependent attribute from multiples entities

Tags: objective-c, core-data

One of my NSManagedObject's attribute depend on various attributes, some of them in a related NSManagedObject.

In a first run, I implemented a simple Transient Attribute for such attribute, but I just discover that it's not possible to use fetch predicate with transient properties.

I need to create an attribute so that:

1. Its value it's calculated using different attributes
2. 1 of the dependent attribute is present in a related NSManagedObject
3. I can do fetch using this attribute as predicate.
4. If I update one of the dependent attributes, the calculated value must be updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use Key value observing to monitor a property being changed in order to keep some calculated property up to date. You can add an observer to the property you want to monitor.

[KVO Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA).

---

**edit:** Reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html)

To do this correctly, you'll want to override the property getter for your calculated property, and create a `keyPathsFOrValuesAffecting<Key>` function.

Apple's example is pretty good, it gives a case where a `fullName` property should be gathered from the `firstName` and `lastName`.

So you would need to implement KVO with this function:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"lastName", @"firstName", nil];
}
```

This will allow your app to be notified anytime those values are modified. Then you'd just override the getter that would be called upon this notification

```
- (NSString *)fullName 
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName, lastName];
}
```

Comment: I have tried with KeyAffectingValuesFor<Key> but even if I modify one of the dependent key the value is not updated. Can you suggest a possible implementation?

Comment: In this way I will not persist the value, so I will not able to fetch using predicate

Comment: I see, in this case, you will need to make your "calculated" attribute a real Core Data attribute. Predicates query the database directly, so you cannot get in between that process. What you CAN do, is observe all of the attributes it depends on, and have it update and save when they change (just like in my example, but you want to override the setter, not the getter). That way, the database will have an updated value at all times. You may need to set up another observer on THAT property to refresh your view whenever it updates.